# How does FlowMapper Plugin work?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, point, line

I downloaded the FlowMapper plugin for Qgis and I can't seem to find any information on how it is supposed to work...

Also the text seems to cut-off and not fully showing for the input fields so I'm not quite sure what the fields should be anyway...

Here is an example of what I mean:
[image]

I tried to select a file storing my node coordinates but am not allowed to (greyed-out) pick files that are .csv, .dbf, .shp or seemingly any of the filetypes on my computer... Which is why I started looking for some information on how to use the FlowMapper plug-in, after finding nothing descriptive I thought it would be easier to ask someone who has maybe used it successfully before.

For reference I have a point file of centroids of polygons and I have a collection of lat long points which contain an attribute that should connect them to one of the above mentioned centroids. Maybe there is a better way to do this?

QGIS 1.8.0 on Mac

Comment: And I did try expanding the window... The content doesn't shift with the window...

Comment: This plugin offers limited help if you already have your flows inside a shapefile, all transformations can be processed inside QGIS (v 2.2), as far as I understand.
If the plugin contained a means to work directly on a shapefile or to import it, instead of importing only txt files, it would be better.
Just my humble opinion.

Answer (score 11):

I am the developer of this plugin. Yet it is still experimental; but fully working.
The plugin pack you have downloaded already includes a PDF TUTORIAL file. Please read it.
Flow mapper plug-in is tested to be working under Windows. Thus, I cannot guarantee it to work under mac-os. It would probably have path problems.

You can only select txt files for input. First should store your node coordinates and second should store the interaction matrix between them. Then you can create node2node flow lines as shapefile.

link to plugin documentation: 
https://github.com/cempro/flowmapper/blob/master/02_documentation/release_notes_v0.2.pdf

Comment: Thanks for joining us on gis.stackexchange and providing support for your plugin. Please keep the conversation here - in public - so everyone can profit from it.

Comment: @cempro link to the docs seems to be dead :/

Comment: @radek https://github.com/cempro/flowmapper/blob/master/02_documentation/release_notes_v0.2.pdf Documentation is rather old and refers the initial versions. Ignore 1st page, OGR/GDAL installation already comes with QGIS.  Download the plugin via plugin manager and run. Operation is pretty straight forward. You need at least two files as TXT. 1st a list of node coordinates, 2nd an interaction table (matrix). You may use excel to prep. data then paste in notepad. Sample data format https://github.com/cempro/flowmapper/tree/master/01_test_data/00_SMALL_SYNTHETIC_TEST_DATA