# "IndexError: list index out of range" error when using FlowMapper plugin in QGIS 2

Tags: qgis-plugins, error, qgis-2, flow-map, indexerror

In QGIS 2.12.0 Lyon I have a problem while using the FlowMapper plugin. But I don't know why. This is the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../python/plugins\FlowMapper\flowmapper.py", line 2656, in run
flowpyv07.shapefilemaker(FlowType,CreateShpNodes,IncludeNodeNames,str(SaveDirectory), str(SaveShpName),str(SaveShpNameNodes),str(InputMatrixName),str(InputNodesName),str(InputNodeNamesName),str(combotext))

File ".../python/plugins\FlowMapper\flowpyv07.py", line 51, in shapefilemaker
onevalue = float(separatestrings[columns])
IndexError: list index out of range

Python-Version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS-Version: 2.12.0-Lyon Lyon, cd9d645
```

Comment: My guess is that you are using float values (numbers with a decimal) which it doesn't like. Perhaps try rounding these values to integers?

Comment: Thank you. I use float value for coordinates. This seems to be the problem (error in line 51). If I read coordinate file in libreoffice, there is no decimal separator. But in txt file there is one. Is this the problem? I will try later.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

I have recently faced the same problem and handled it.

Therefore, I am providing some hints for those who are still struggling:

- Text file (*.txt*) that stores **node coordinates** should be in the following format:

  [image: Proper_coordinates]

  - No column titles, e.g. long, lat.
  - Coordinates go only with dots
  - Space in between long and lat, not TAB.
- Text file (*.txt*) that defines **flow matrix** should look like:

  [image: Proper_matrix]

  - Space in between matrix values, not TAB.
  - All empty values are 0 (numbers zero), not `NULL` or Empty space.
  - Delete other empty columns and rows where data is not stored.

Then everything should work as intended.

I am using the  Notepad++ for replacing: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

---

**References:**

- [How does FlowMapper Plugin work?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56666/how-does-flowmapper-plugin-work)
- [Fill Empty Cell With 0 Number In Excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wJKXzTLKT8)