# NameError: global name is not defined when performing task with FlowMapper in QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2, error, flow-map

I'm using QGIS 2.8 and I'm trying to apply the FlowMapper plugin to create a visualization. I aim to follow the instructions in [this](http://urbantalks.in/origin-destination-matrix-gis-easy-way/) blog post and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184395/flowmapper-plugin-error-in-qgis-2-12-0-lyon) GIS.SE question, but something seem be going wrong.

The error is as follows:

> 2020-11-04T19:45:59   1   Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/FlowMapper/flowmapper.py",
> line 2655, in run
> SaveDirectory = SaveShpName             NameError: global name 'SaveShpName' is not defined

I'm not sure what to do about this. So far, I've tried changing the input files by either switching to spaces instead of tabs between the data columns. That did not help though.

Added: Here are the files I've used. First, there is the locations of the cities:
[image]

Then there's the labels associated with them:
[image]

And finally, the incidence matrix:
[image]

All columns are separated by spaces. The paths to the respective files are:

> /Users/maxmuller100/Documents/Data_Project/stud-steden-locaties.txt

and

> /Users/maxmuller100/Documents/Data_Project/stud-steden-labels.txt

and

> /Users/maxmuller100/Documents/Data_Project/stud-steden-matrix.txt

Comment: @Taras Thank you for the link to that document. I'm not really sure how to answer your question. What symbols do you mean? By the way, do you think it'd help If I showed screenshots of the input files I've made?

Comment: @Taras I've added the files! I'm very interested to hear what you think about them.

Comment: @Taras I've added the path names of the text files at the end of the question

Comment: @Taras I'm afraid not, I get the same error message.

Comment: @Taras Yeah maybe it's better to try another workflow. I think I'm going to follow the approach in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXp0FJAkql0

Comment: @Taras Sure. I'm not sure how though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error in line 2655 refers to this part of the code in *flowmapper.py*

```py
#SaveDirectory = os.path.realpath(SaveShpName)
SaveDirectory = SaveShpName
flowpyv07.shapefilemaker(FlowType,CreateShpNodes,IncludeNodeNames,str(SaveDirectory), str(SaveShpName),str(SaveShpNameNodes),str(InputMatrixName),str(InputNodesName),str(InputNodeNamesName),str(combotext))
```

and it appears because `SaveShpName` was incorrectly initialized in *flowpyv07.py* via the function

```py
def shapefilemaker(typeofcalculation,CreateShpNodes,IncludeNodeNames,fulldirectorystring,outputfilename,outputfilenamenodes,fulldirODinput,fulldirPTinput,fulldirPTNamesinput,combotext):
```

where some(or all) variables `fulldirODinput,fulldirPTinput,fulldirPTNamesinput` can not be created with a built-in function [`open(filename, 'r')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) probably due to issues in the input file content or a path to each of them.

So, there are several solutions I may suggest:

---

**A short-time solution**

I could get the desired flows in QGIS Wien 2.8.9, see image below.

[image: result]

When I opened your initial file `"stud-steden-matrix.txt"` in Notepad++ I see this

[image: notepad++]

but when I open the same file in simple Windows's Notepad the result is different

[image: notepad]

So, all text files have to be formatted appropriately.

This is a FlowMapper's working window:

[image: flow_mapper_window]

---

**A long-time solution**

1. I assume that the Plugin's developer (@cempro) will highly appreciate if you can assist with FlowMapper [Plugin migration to QGIS 3](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/wiki/Plugin-migration-to-QGIS-3).
2. Using a Virtual Layer, implementation was described in [this article](https://anitagraser.com/2019/05/04/flow-maps-in-qgis-no-plugins-needed/).
3. Setting a new workflow for QGIS 3 and putting as a possible solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160350/creating-flow-maps-in-qgis). For instance, I just implemented a workflow with native QGIS tools.

   1. Import a text file with points
      [image: step_11]
      [image: step_12]
   2. Generating all possible line connections between all points, you can use one of the possible approach described in [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366235/creating-all-possible-line-segments-between-all-points-using-qgis).

      For example, I used solution with a Virtual Layer with the following query

      ```sql
       select a.id || '_' || b.id as keyf, a.id as fromp, b.id as top, makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry
       from "stud-steden-locaties" a, "stud-steden-locaties" b
       where a.id <> b.id
      ```

      *Note:* Here I created a special field with `a.id || '_' || b.id` this will play a key role in joining attributes from `"stud-steden-matrix-list.csv"`

      [image: step_2]
   3. Drag&Drop `"stud-steden-matrix-list.csv"` into QGIS and apply a simple join between lines and `.csv`-file.

      [image: step_31]
      [image: step_32]
   4. Apply some visualization techniques to get flows, see image below

      [image: result]

      It is possibly a complicated solution, so you may find a smarter one.

---

**References:**

- [Adjusting flow map styles in QGIS 2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314057/adjusting-flow-map-styles-in-qgis-2)
- ['Global name not defined' concept in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916300/global-name-not-defined-concept-in-python)
- [FlowMapper Documentation](https://github.com/cempro/flowmapper/blob/master/02_documentation/release_notes_v0.2.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for all your help!